# FeatureStyleModifier in MapInfo to give translucent effect

Tags: c#, mapxtreme

We are trying to give the translucency to all features in a particular feature layer while retaining the styles of each feature in that layer.

We tried following approach :
       http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/techsupp/miprod.nsf/59d125f456480edb852562b5004f2c33/00a4a56ebede26ff85256fe30054e255?OpenDocument

In this approach the `Modify()` function is not getting hit and hence not working properly. Code inside the `Modify()` function is not getting executed at all, as per the article that it should get called once the modifier is appended.

Following is the code snippet we are using:

```
Internal class SelectedAreaModifier : FeatureStyleModifier
{
    private System.Collections.Hashtable features;
    public SelectedAreaModifier(string name, string alias, IResultSetFeatureCollection irfc) : base(name, alias)
    {
        features = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
        string[] exp = new string[] { "MI_KEY" };
        this.Expressions = exp;

        foreach (Feature f in irfc)
        {            
            features.Add(f.Key.Value, f.Key.Value);
        }
    }

    protected override bool Modify(FeatureStyleStack styles, object[] values)
    {
        MapInfo.Styles.CompositeStyle cs = styles.Current;
        if (features.Contains((values[0] as MapInfo.Data.Key).Value))
        {
            (cs.AreaStyle.Interior as SimpleInterior).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb((int)(255 * .5), (cs.AreaStyle.Interior as SimpleInterior).ForeColor);
            (cs.AreaStyle.Border as SimpleLineStyle).Color = Color.FromArgb((int)(255 * .5),(cs.AreaStyle.Border as SimpleLineStyle).Color);
            (cs.AreaStyle.Border as SimpleLineStyle).Width = (cs.AreaStyle.Border as SimpleLineStyle).Width;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this class is being used as :

```
protected void setTranslucency() 
{
    Map myMap = GetMapObj();
    myMap.DrawingAttributes.EnableTranslucency = true;
    myMap.DrawingAttributes.SmoothingMode = MapInfo.Mapping.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    myMap.DrawingAttributes.SpecialTransparentVectorHandling = false;

    FeatureLayer ftrLyr = myMap.Layers["CELL_2G"] as FeatureLayer;

    if (ftrLyr.Modifiers["CELL_2G_Translucent"] != null)
        ftrLyr.Modifiers.Remove("CELL_2G_Translucent");

    MapInfo.Data.MIConnection connection = new MIConnection();
    connection.Open();
    MapInfo.Data.MICommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "select * from CELL_3G";
    command.Prepare();

    IResultSetFeatureCollection irfc = command.ExecuteFeatureCollection();

    SelectedAreaModifier sam = new SelectedAreaModifier("CELL_2G_Translucent", "CELL_2G_Translucent", irfc);
    sam.Enabled = true;

    ftrLyr.Modifiers.Append(sam);

    irfc.Close();
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
 Monu

Comment: Question is not about MapInfo, tag should be removed.

Comment: Its related to MapInfo coding. **FeatureStyleModifier** class comes in **MapInfo.Mapping** namespace.

Comment: MapInfo tag means the desktop GIS application "MapInfo Professional". MapXtreme is a completely separate SDK product, but also from Pitney Bowes.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, i will remove MapInfo tag and keep only MapXtreme.

Comment: I think you should have posted it at http://gis.stackexchange.com/, but I have no idea how to move a question.

Comment: Thanks.....i posted it. Copied/Pasted question manually there.